# Паттерн заказ-поставка, как привязать поставку строго к одному заказу

Tags: sql, база-данных

Как средствами БД реализовать жёсткую привязку одной поставки к одному заказу? Пример - покупатель оформляет заказ, который может быть выполнен несколькими поставками. Создаём схему данных примерно вот с такими связями:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как видно, поставка связана строго с одним заказом. Тем не менее, это не мешает создать в таблице "Строка" записи, типа:

```
Заказ  Поставка Название
1      1        Книга1
2      1        Книга2
```

То есть ограничение целостности не нарушается - поставка по-прежнему относится к одному заказу, НО при этом в таблице "Строка" есть запись, свидетельствующая о том, что товар в поставке выполнен для разных заказов.

Comment: А что за название в "строка". Если связь должна быть один к    одному то чаще всего делается не отдельная таблица, а ID выдачи заносится непосредственно в возвраты или наоборот, в зависимости от обязательности присутствия в БД одного или другого

Comment: И кстати какое отношение "заказ" и "поставка" о которых речь в начале имеет к Выдаче и Возврату  ? Если на 1 заказ несколько поставок то в таблице поставок заносится ID заказа к которому она  относится. дополнительной таблицы связи не требуется

Comment: @Mike поправил картинку, чтобы избежать неправильного толкования. Название в таблице заказ - это FK к таблице "Товар" в оригинальной БД. Здесь я просто оставил название. Заказ включает в себя несколько товаров (пример - книга1, Книга2, книга3). Заказ может реализовываться несколькими поставками. В первой поставке книга1 и книга2, во второй - книга3. Задача - сделать так, чтобы одна поставка ограничивалась одним заказом.

Comment: Такую проверку лучше всего будет выполнить триггером на таблицу "Строка", который проверит, что ID заказа из изменяемой записи совпадает с ID заказа из  приписываемой поставки. А чисто архитектурное решение будет дико не красивым и с ним будет тяжело работать

Comment: @mike хотел красиво и без триггеров. Получается что связь поставки и заказа избыточна, так как ничего, по сути, не запрещает?

Comment: Ну она нужна что бы триггер мог проверить ваше условие. потому как триггер не сможет обратится к другим записям той таблицы на которую создан, он не сможет убедится, что создаваемая запись к тому же заказу что и уже существующие. хотя в теории она действительно избыточна

Comment: А что касается архитектурного решения, надо добавлять еще одну сущность между заказами и товарами. группы товаров. В одном заказе много групп в каждой группе много товаров. и поставки ссылаются на группы. Но по факту выходит что придется перетасовывать товары между группами ради привязки их к поставкам. т.е. при создании заказов группа одна, а по мере выполнения заказа, если поставок несколько, создаются новые группы и часть товаров переезжает в них. глюкодром будет тот еще

Comment: Поле строка.заказ у вас лишнее. Уберите его и используйте строка.поставка.заказ. Денормализация подобного рода всегда предполагает лишние телодвижения по сохранению целостности данных.

Comment: @vp_arth если из _Строка_ убрать _заказ_, то тогда мы не сможем узнать, какие товары входят в заказ. То есть заказ уже есть, а поставки может ещё и не быть.

Answer (score 0):

> если из Строка убрать заказ, то тогда мы не сможем узнать, какие товары входят в заказ. То есть заказ уже есть, а поставки может ещё и не быть.

В этом случае, Строка не нужно знать о поставке.

Можно сделать связь `Поставка-Строка` много-к-многим, чтобы не исключать включение товаров из нескольких заказов в одну поставку:

- Заказ(id)
- Строка(id, id_заказ)
- Поставка(id)
- ПоставкаСтрока(id, id_поставка, id_строка)

Либо добавить поле `заказ` в `Поставка` плюс пара триггеров(insert/update), которые будут проверять равенство `ПоставкаСтрока.Строка.Заказ` и `ПоставкаСтрока.Поставка.Заказ`:

- Заказ(id)
- Строка(id, id_заказ)
- Поставка(id, id_заказ)
- ПоставкаСтрока(id, id_поставка, id_строка)

Ко всему прочему, вероятно не будет лишним уникальный индекс на поле ПоставкаСтрока.id_строка